# How do I add unique links to each image in my pure css slider?

Tags: css, hyperlink, slider, gallery, slideshow

Original:

CSS:

```
    .wavsplashslider {position: relative; height:392px; overflow:hidden; }
    .slideimg:hover {cursor:pointer}
    .wavsplashslide {position: absolute;top: 0; left: 0;z-index: -5;
    -webkit-animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;-moz-animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;-ms-animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;-o-animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;}
    .wavsplashslide:hover {cursor:pointer}
    .wavsplashslide:nth-child(2) {z-index: -4;-webkit-animation: slideshow 12s linear 4s infinite;-moz-animation: slideshow 12s linear 4s infinite;-ms-animation: slideshow 12s linear 4s infinite;-o-animation: slideshow 12s linear 4s infinite;animation: slideshow 12s linear 4s infinite;}
    .wavsplashslide:nth-child(3) {z-index: -3;
    -webkit-animation: slideshow 12s linear 8s infinite;-moz-animation: slideshow 12s linear 8s infinite;-ms-animation: slideshow 12s linear 8s infinite;-o-animation: slideshow 12s linear 8s infinite;animation: slideshow 12s linear 8s infinite;}
    @-webkit-keyframes slideshow {25% { opacity: 1;}33.33% { opacity: 0;} 91.66% { opacity: 0;}100% { opacity: 1;}}
    @-moz-keyframes slideshow {25% { opacity: 1;}33.33% { opacity: 0;} 91.66% { opacity: 0;}100% { opacity: 1;}}
    @-ms-keyframes slideshow {25% { opacity: 1;}33.33% { opacity: 0;}  91.66% { opacity: 0;}100% { opacity: 1;}}
    @-o-keyframes slideshow {25% { opacity: 1;}33.33% { opacity: 0;} 91.66% { opacity: 0;}100% { opacity: 1;}}
    @keyframes slideshow {25% { opacity: 1;}33.33% { opacity: 0;} 91.66% { opacity: 0;}100% { opacity: 1;}}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="wavsplashslider">
    <div class="wavsplashslide">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="bird.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="wavsplashslide">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions"><img src="solid.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="wavsplashslide">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/tags"><img src="design.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

UPDATED:

Thanks for the help! Can anyone now give me a hint as to how to slow down slides? I would like all the slides to display for the same duration as the first slide on page load, but after the first slide they start cycling rather quickly.

```
.wavsplashslider {position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;  width: 824px; height:392px; overflow:hidden; }
.wavsplashslide {width: 824px; height:392px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;-webkit-animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;-moz-animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;-ms-animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;-o-animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;}
.wavsplashslide:nth-child(2) {-webkit-animation: slideshow 12s linear 4s infinite;-moz-animation: slideshow 12s linear 4s infinite;-ms-animation: slideshow 12s linear 4s infinite;-o-animation: slideshow 12s linear 4s infinite;animation: slideshow 12s linear 4s infinite;}
.wavsplashslide:nth-child(3) {-webkit-animation: slideshow 12s linear 8s infinite;-moz-animation: slideshow 12s linear 8s infinite;-ms-animation: slideshow 12s linear 8s infinite;-o-animation: slideshow 12s linear 8s infinite;animation: slideshow 12s linear 8s infinite;}

@-webkit-keyframes slideshow {25% { opacity: 1; left: 0;} 33.33% { opacity: 0;left: -824px;} 91.66% { opacity: 0;left: -824px;} 100% { opacity: 1; left: 0}}
@-moz-keyframes slideshow {25% { opacity: 1; left: 0;} 33.33% { opacity: 0;left: -824px;} 91.66% { opacity: 0;left: -824px;} 100% { opacity: 1; left: 0}}
@-ms-keyframes slideshow {25% { opacity: 1; left: 0;} 33.33% { opacity: 0;left: -824px;} 91.66% { opacity: 0;left: -824px;} 100% { opacity: 1; left: 0}}
@-o-keyframes slideshow {25% { opacity: 1; left: 0;} 33.33% { opacity: 0;left: -824px;} 91.66% { opacity: 0;left: -824px;} 100% { opacity: 1; left: 0}}
@keyframes slideshow {25% { opacity: 1; left: 0;} 33.33% { opacity: 0;left: -824px;} 91.66% { opacity: 0;left: -824px;} 100% { opacity: 1; left: 0}}




<div class="wavsplashslider">

<div class="wavsplashslide">
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/824/392"  />
</a>
</div>


<div class="wavsplashslide">
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/824/392" />
</a>
</div>

<div class="wavsplashslide">
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/tags">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/824/392" />
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're currently only making slides transparent -- you need to actually move them out of the way so users can click on the elements below them.

Answer (score 0):

Your class .wavsplashslide{} has no width or height. If you notice in the top left of your slider there will be small clickable box. Set an appropriate width and height and it should work. Also, remove the z-index attribute as it's causing the parent element to have a higher layer priority and covering up .wavsplashslide{}.

```
.wavsplashslide {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 392px; width: 1170px; ...animations}
```